# Does umbraco work on mono?

Tags: mono, umbraco, mojoportal

I'd like to run [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) on Mono. Is this possible?

Comment: Why the downvote? A perfectly reasonable question.  (Albeit better suited for Serverfault)

Comment: @Michael - true, but there's probably a valid developer angle because the code may need tweaking to make it Mono friendly.

Comment: Is it really argument for downvoting? thousands of companies use Umbraco because OpenSource and ASP.NET. The same reasons why to use mono. Logical consequence - marry them together.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Umbraco does not run properly on Mono but there are known efforts to achieve that goal. [This](http://kevinfitzgerald.net/articles/umbraco-and-mono.htm) will give a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

A community effort has been made to port Umbraco (v4.x) to work on Mono.

https://github.com/m57j75/umbracoMono

At the time of writing, there is a beta of v4.7.2, with work already started on bringing in the v4.11.x changes.