# How to install Umbraco 7.X.X on the Mono Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono, umbraco

I want to install Umbraco 7.X.X on the Mono Framework.

https://our.umbraco.org/download

Hosting the Umbraco database on a MySQL-server and running the website under apache with mod_mono.

There are a few of old topics about this subject (founded via Google), for example this post from 5 years ago.

[Does umbraco work on mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648131/does-umbraco-work-on-mono)

There changed a lot last years. Does anyone know if it's possible nowadays and how?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 6):

Officially it is not designed for Linux and Mono,

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Requirements/

So either you plan to port it to Linux/Mono by yourself, or you sponsor somebody else to do so.